# Mattermost: Invalid or expired session, please login again

Tags: bearer-token, mattermost

I am facing an issue where I am getting a 401 response with message 'Invalid or expired session, please login again' when I hit the `/users/me` API. This is happening even if I am sending the bearer token which was genereate from the `/login` API.

Here is the request:

```
curl -X GET \
  http://localhost:8065/api/v4/users/me \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer 4p7ip3wuujby7cfmeqb7718fhc' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: eac220fa-9208-427b-b76f-f048ba28908a' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

Comment: i tested today, using 5.8.0 version and after the login can copy the token this curl worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token you receive after login is a temporary token. It will expire after some time. You have two options to overcome that:

1. Login again and get a fresh token.
2. Use Personal Access Token which is a valid token and also it does not expire unless you revoke it by intention.

If you want to use [Personal Access Token](https://docs.mattermost.com/developer/personal-access-tokens.html?highlight=personal%20access%20token#personal-access-tokens) first you need to enable it in the config file. Set `EnableUserAccessTokens` to `true`. Then reset your server to apply the config. After that, use [the specific endpoint](https://api.mattermost.com/#tag/users%2Fpaths%2F~1users~1%7Buser_id%7D~1tokens%2Fpost) to create a Personal Access Token for your account. Pay attention that, by default, only System Admins have permissions to create a personal access token.